# Problems With My Web Crawler (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, google-chrome-headless

I have a little strange question, but I hope somebody can solve it anyway, because I've already tried so much and I just couldn't get any further. Thanks in advance 
 
I have a problem with my Python script. To be precise, it's not just one problem. The aim of my script is to automatically search for keywords from a list in a search engine (www.startpage.com). Then it should count how often there is a search word on the search engine's results-page. If the searchword occurs  more than 14 times there, it will be saved in a list. If it is less than 14 times, in another.
 
My problem now is that there are always errors. The program runs about 20 times (with success), but then,t there is just some error. The problem here is that the mistake is simply not correct. For example, an error occurs that says that a variable is undefined even though it is. Or another error looks like this:

```
  File "webcrawler.py", line 42, in <module>
    email_count=get_results(liste[x])
  File "webcrawler.py", line 28, in get_results
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

But this mistake doesn't really make sense, since the program ran 20 times without errors.
 My code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

#opens textfile with list of all search terms
with open("list1.txt") as infile:
   list1 = [list1.strip() for list1 in infile]



#this function searches for "search_term" on the website www.startpage.com
def get_results(search_term):
    url="https://www.startpage.com"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        search_box = browser.find_element_by_id("q")
    except NoSuchElementException:
            print("An error occured!")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    time.sleep(3)
    source_code = (browser.page_source).strip().lower()
    browser.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    email=search_term.lower()
    return source_code.count(email)



#textfiles for the results
f = open("works.txt", "a")
g = open("works_not.txt", "a")

x=0
while x < len(list1):
    email_count=get_results(list1[x]) 

#saves listitem to result file (sorted after how often the search term appeared on the results page)
    if email_count < 15:
        g.write(list1[x])
        g.write("\n")
        g.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        f.write(list1[x])
        f.write("\n")
        f.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    x=x+1
```

Is there something wrong with the code or should I add "sleep ()" somewhere? I'm sorry that this is such a strange question, but I hope someone sees the problem. 
A thousand thanks in advance.

Comment: Addendum: I don't think the problem has anything to do with the error I stated. The most common mistake I see is that the variable "search_box" is not defined. This means that the "try-except" did not go through. But as I said: I only get this error after many runs (which work)

Comment: I currently had this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcrawler.py", line 43, in <module>
    email_count=get_results(liste[x])
  File "webcrawler.py", line 28, in get_results
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'search_box' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Look at the `try` around the line when `search_box` gets assigned. If there is an exception, you print an error message, then continue as if the error hadn't happened. In that scenario `search_box` will be undefined. Generally try to reduce your question to a [mre]; very often, you will figure out the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: The other error happens when there isn't an exception, but the extracted value is a string, not an object of whichever type you were hoping and expecting to get back, and so of course the string doesn't have the method that you are trying to call.

Comment: Both of these are very common beginner errors with lots of answers on Stack Overflow already; you should search before asking.